# what are invalid character for anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

my application was developed in asp.net mvc 4. we have list of jobs.

now we have allowed all special characters in job name, but

```
</ characters causes issue in creating <a> anchor tag. I have also tried to create anchor tag with these character on w3schools.com example. I noticed the same thing.

for example, job name => Test </ Test
but it will render ONLY "Test" NOT "Test </ Test".
```

We are creating this link in "fnRowCallback" using javascript as it is listing of jobs and for that we have used jquery datatable http://legacy.datatables.net/.

Please help me, how to prevent the characters using regular expression on JobName model property.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check: [Description to allowed characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487494/parsing-invalid-anchor-tag-with-beautifulsoup-or-regex)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean for the display part of the anchor tag, everything should be fine - you should be getting ASP.NET MVC to perform any escaping required to represent your text properly in HTML, e.g. using [`@Html.AnchorLink(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). It's far better to be able to escape everything than to have to restrict your input :)

In general, raw data should *never* be written directly to the HTML - it can represent a huge security risk, for example. It should *always* be handled with the appropriate escaping, which should almost always be performed by the web presentation framework you're using rather than by any hand-crafted code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. but we have to create <a> link using javascript as it is listing of jobs and for that we have jquery datatable http://legacy.datatables.net/